# Set a multilne default value for a enviroment variable in Spring yml

Tags: spring, yaml

Ok so I got a spring boot application. And I have a key

```
faf-api:
  jwt:
    secret-key: ${JWT_SECRETE_KEY: secrete key}
```

That I wanna set to "secrete key" unless there is a environment variable called `JWT_SECRETE_KEY`. The only thing is the "secrete key" is actually a multi-line `String(RSA key)`. I know how to make multi-line strings in `yaml` but `${}` is a Spring thing so I can not do it in there. Could not find anything on that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this :

```
secret-key: ${JWT_SECRETE_KEY: #{secrete key}}
```

Or I don't understand the problem